Problems testing with pytest with mock in a subclass
I'm having problems trying to mock a class called into another class.
I have three modules:
tree.py
from branch import Branch

class Tree:

    type_of_tree = None
    branches = None

    def __init__(self, type_of_tree, branches = 0, default_leaves = 0):
        self.type_of_tree = type_of_tree
        self.branches = []
        for branch in range(branches):
            self.create_branch(default_leaves)


    def create_branch(self, leaves):
        self.branches.append(Branch(leaves))


    def get_leaves(self):
        return_value = []
        for branch in self.branches:
            return_value.extend(branch.get_leaves())
        return return_value

branch.py
import uuid
from leave import Leave


class Branch:
    leaves = None
    identifier = None

    def __init__(self, leaves=0):
        self.identifier = str(uuid.uuid4())
        self.leaves = []
        for leave in range(leaves):
            self.create_leave()

    def create_leave(self):
        self.leaves.append(Leave())

    def get_leaves(self):
        return_value = []
        for leave in self.leaves:
            return_value.append(leave.get_identifier())
        return return_value

leave.py
import uuid


class Leave:
    identifier = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.identifier = str(uuid.uuid4())

    def get_identifier(self):
        return self.identifier


I'm trying to mock Leave class with this code:
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
from uuid import uuid4

from tree import Tree

FAKE_UUID = str(uuid4())

class TestLeave:


    def test_leave(self):
        with patch('leave.Leave') as mock_leave:
            mock_leave.return_value = MagicMock()
            mock_leave.get_identifier.return_value = FAKE_UUID
            tree = Tree("Pine", 1, 1)
            leaves = tree.get_leaves()
            assert leaves == [FAKE_UUID]

The test is failing. I have been reading patch documentation but I don't find related info.

I have found my mistake reading: https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch
The proper way to mock leave class is patching the class imported from branch:
from unittest.mock import patch
from uuid import uuid4

from tree import Tree

FAKE_UUID = str(uuid4())


class TestLeave:

    def test_leave(self):
        with patch('branch.Leave') as mock_leave:
            mock_leave.return_value.get_identifier.return_value = FAKE_UUID
            tree = Tree("Pine", 1, 1)
            leaves = tree.get_leaves()
            assert leaves == [FAKE_UUID]


On this example the test works properly. Pay attention you need to get the object with mock_leave.return_value and then mock the return value with get_identifier.return_value = FAKE_UUID
